# What's the correct way to respond to error page in a POST action without redirect in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I think it's a basic situation. I have a `POST` action, and I want to respond a 403 status and show the error page.

```
def signup(conn, params) do
  ...
  conn
  |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(:forbidden, "Forbidden")
  |> Plug.Conn.halt()
end
```

However, it will return the 403 but not render the error page. Instead, it throw `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()` in browser and download a weird `signup.dms` file.

I have an designed `403.html.eex`, does anyone know how to show it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `render` your template before you `halt`. It could look something like this:

```
conn
|> put_status(:forbidden)
|> put_view(MyApp.ErrorView)
|> render("403.html")
|> halt()
```

In this case you would need to create `MyApp.ErrorView` and create `403.html.eex` in `templates/error`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to download a `*.dms` file is that I didn't set the `Content-Type` for the response.

```
def signup(conn, params) do
  ...
  conn
  |> Plug.Conn.update_resp_header("content-type", "text/plain", &(&1 <> "; charset=utf-8"))
  |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(:forbidden, "Forbidden")
  |> Plug.Conn.halt()
end
```